# Searchkick only return certain values, not all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

When using [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) to perform a search I get all fields as a result. I would like to limit the response to only output certain fields like `title`.

```
# movie.rb
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick autocomplete: ['title']
end

# search_controller.rb
def autocomplete
  render json: Movie.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10, fields: [:title])
end
```

My response is still

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Megamind","director":"Tom McGrath","genre":"Animation | Action | Comedy","description":"The supervillain Megamind finally defeats his nemesis, the superhero Metro Man. But without a hero, he loses all purpose and must find new meaning to his life.","length":95,"year":2010,"imdb_id":"tt1001526","imdb_rating":"7.3","created_at":"2016-04-16T19:50:24.893Z","updated_at":"2016-04-16T19:50:24.893Z"}]
```

I am trying to only get the title back. Reading through different questions I assumed it should have to do with `fields` in my search, but that doesn't change the response. I also tried using the `_source`-attribute, but no luck.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
select_v2: ["title"], load: false
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately if I use `Movie.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10, fields: [:title], select: ["title"])` I still get everything back. Or should I place `select: ["title"]` somewhere else?

Comment: What version of Searchkick are you on?

Comment: Version `1.2.1`. So basically newest

Comment: Try it with `load: false`.

Comment: the `load: false` works :). thanks! Now it only sends back `title` with these extra fields, `index, type, id, score`.

Comment: only weird thing is that is returns the `"title":["Avatar"]` as an array. but that's fine after all

Comment: Use `select_v2: ["title"]` to fix the array issue.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude few fields? If I have a large list of fields and I just want to exclude a few.

Answer (score 1):

for Elasticsearch version `5.6.3` and searchkick gem version `2.1.1` this works: `select: ["languages", "categories", "level", "id"], load: false` to return only these fields

Answer (score -1):

So basically I figured a way around it. As I am getting all fields back in my response I just filter them before sending them to the client:

```
search = Movie.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10, fields: [:title])
search = search.results.map do |m|
  { title: m.title }
end

render json: search
```

My query returns all values, but I just send those I want back. It would be nicer to have the query just return the fields I want, but this works as a solution for now :)